# BadMethodCallException: Wrong number of parameters

Tags: php, phalcon

As I am new to Phalcon framework, I did not find the solution for my problem. Here is the query that I am trying to use:

```
    $withdraws = Withdrawals::query()
        ->columns('Withdrawals.cashboxId', 'Withdrawals.amount', 'Withdrawals.createdAt', 'Withdrawals.status', 'Withdrawals.serialNo', 'u.firstName', 'u.lastName')
        ->innerJoin('Shop\Domain\Clients\Models\Clients', 'Withdrawals.userId = u.id', 'u')
        ->where('Withdrawals.cashboxId = :cashboxId:', ['cashboxId' => $cashboxId])
        ->andWhere('Withdrawals.status = :status:', ['status' => 1])
        ->execute();
```

It gives me `BadMethodCallException: Wrong number of parameters`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As an aside, if status is hardcoded as 1, then don't bother with a placeholder.

Comment: Is there any more to the error message such as a stack-trace or even line number? Which method call is the _"bad one"_?

Comment: @Phil line number is 19 which starts with `->columns...`

Comment: Looks like `columns()` accepts only a single argument. For multiple columns, use an array. See https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder#methods

Comment: That looks right @Phil offtopic typo.  Wrap the csv in square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution was I changed:

```
->columns('Withdrawals.cashboxId', 'Withdrawals.amount', 'Withdrawals.createdAt', 'Withdrawals.status', 'Withdrawals.serialNo', 'u.firstName', 'u.lastName')
```

to

```
->columns('Shop\Domain\Withdrawals\Models\Withdrawals.cashboxId, 
Shop\Domain\Withdrawals\Models\Withdrawals.amount, 
Shop\Domain\Withdrawals\Models\Withdrawals.createdAt, 
Shop\Domain\Withdrawals\Models\Withdrawals.status, 
Shop\Domain\Withdrawals\Models\Withdrawals.serialNo, 
u.firstName, u.lastName')
```

and it worked for me. Besides columns accepting single parameter, I also had to write the full path for `Withdrawals` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

`->columns()` expects one argument, a string or array.

Try this

```php
$withdraws = Withdrawals::query()
        ->columns(['Withdrawals.cashboxId', 'Withdrawals.amount', 'Withdrawals.createdAt', 'Withdrawals.status', 'Withdrawals.serialNo', 'u.firstName', 'u.lastName'])
        ->innerJoin('Shop\Domain\Clients\Models\Clients', 'Withdrawals.userId = u.id', 'u')
        ->where('Withdrawals.cashboxId = :cashboxId:', ['cashboxId' => $cashboxId])
        ->andWhere('Withdrawals.status = :status:', ['status' => 1])
        ->execute();
```